# /etc/passwd shortest password

Tags: password, root

I need to put one character inside the password file so that nobody can notice.
I thought that if I was able to put the password as plain text and put something like a space nobody would ever find out. But I don't know how to put plain text in the /etc/passwd or /etc/shadow file.
Is there any way to put just one character or a really short string in there so that if someone opens that file doesn't even notice that for instance gnats has a password.

Example:

```
gnats: :16273:0:99999:7:::
```

OR

```
gnats:8:16273:0:99999:7:::
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no. The formats of these files are very specific, and the password field strings are hashes which will have a minimum length of 8 characters, 16 or more on more modern versions that use stronger password hashing. If you're looking for a way to just put in a text string, look at the gecos field in `/etc/passwd`. If you want a way to have an "invisible" password, you're out of luck in dealing with these two files.

Comment: Seems like my best way to do this is just remove the X in /etc/passwd and that way I will be able to just "su - user" and do my thing without typing any password. And it's the most unnoticeable thing that I've come up with in the last 5 minutes.

Comment: You really do not want a user that someone is able to log in to without a password. Seriously, just don't do it.

Comment: @John Depends whether you're the attacker or the defender…

Answer (score 1):

To generate the encrypted password you can use the perl function

```
perl -e 'print crypt(" ","\$6\$saltsalt\$") . "\n"'
```

which will give:

```
6$saltsalt$dbMv1WdXXWhYJXZCacilMdWabQOTCkYM.6OIQb/.md67MGEi2mORqm2dx6vAzJ.frP0Nm7m/c8lMQq5OFRTM0/
```

- replace *saltsalt* by any random string

Please note that you cannot put a plain text password in `/etc/passwd` or `/etc/shadow`.